# ¿Cómo puedo unir 3 tablas SQL?

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando unir los campos de 3 tablas.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT lovi.id_lovi, 
       u.nombre, 
       h.id_hallazgos 

FROM usuarios AS u

JOIN hallazgos AS h 
ON h.id_usuarios = u.id_usuarios 

RIGHT JOIN lovi AS l
ON l.id_usuarios = u.id_usuarios
```

En las tres tablas tengo el campo `id_usuarios`, pero la consulta me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: tabla con las 3 columnas del select y algunos valores]

Comment: Cuál es el resultado que esperas al ejecutar esa consulta, podrías poner un ejemplo?

Comment: id_lovi 18|id_hallazgos 157| nombre tester

Comment: todos los id_lovi e id_hallazgos que pertenezcan a tester

Answer (score 8):

> Todos los id_lovi e id_hallazgos que pertenezcan a tester

```
SELECT lovi.id_lovi, hallazgos.id_hallazgos 
FROM usuarios
JOIN hallazgos ON hallazgos.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuarios 
JOIN lovi ON lovi.id_usuarios = usuarios.id_usuarios
WHERE usuarios.nombre LIKE '%tester%'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select C.nombre as Cliente,
A.nombre as Asociacion,
M.fechaIncorporacion as FechaIncorporacion,  
M.estatusMiembro as Estatus
from Miembros M
inner join Asociaciones A on A.idAsosiacion =M.idAsosiacion 
inner join Clientes C on C.idCliente = M.idCliente
```

Comment: Respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad revisa [answer]

Comment: Agrega por favor una explicación de como tu repuesta puede ayudar a resolver la problematica.